# MySQL multi-query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am using the following script:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$file = file_get_contents('./dump.sql');

//var_dump($file); die();

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'myUserName', 'myPassWord', 'myDataBase');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $conn->host_info . "<br />";
echo 'Retrieving dumpfile' . "<br />";

$sql = $file;
if (!$sql){
    die ('Error opening file');
}

echo 'processing file <br />';
mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql);

echo 'done.';
$conn->close();

?>
```

It outputs the following and all appears to go well with no errors at all:

```
Success... localhost via TCP/IP
Retrieving dumpfile
processing file
done.
```

However, there are no fields in my database.  Nothing ever gets added.

The first lines of code in my dump.sql file are as follows:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 05, 2012 at 04:01 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `myDataBase`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `content_field_image_cache`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_field_image_cache` (
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_image_cache_fid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_image_cache_list` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_image_cache_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`,`delta`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `content_field_image_cache`
--

INSERT INTO `content_field_image_cache` (`vid`, `nid`, `delta`, `field_image_cache_fid`, `field_image_cache_list`, `field_image_cache_data`) VALUES
(1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 1, NULL),
(1001, 1001, 0, 1001, 1, NULL),
(1002, 1002, 0, 1002, 1, NULL),
(1003, 1003, 0, 1003, 1, NULL),
```

Why isn't this code working?  Thanks.

Comment: Any error messages? What does mysqli_multi_query return?

Comment: what does mysqli_multi_query() returns? is there something in mysql_error() after calling it?

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query` returns `bool(false)`.

Comment: It seems like there's a `,` after your last statement; it should be a semicolon. `;`. Syntax error...

Comment: The code provided is just a sample. The file is actually much larger. It doesn't end with a comma; the SQL file was generated by phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @user1477388 the query is failing, output the result of `mysqli_error()` to see the error messaage.

Comment: What is the error returned by `mysqli_error($conn)`?

Comment: When I do `var_dump($conn->error);` it says, "MySQL server has gone away."

Comment: One other note:  The `dump.sql` file is from phpMyAdmin version 3.4.5.  The server I am trying to insert it into is of version 3.5.1.  Does that cause a problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The dump file should contain only valid sql statements and comments so the version does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to iterate through the results to get rid of the `MySQL server has gone away.` error:

In the simplest form (untested example):

```
mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql);

// You can do something with the results as well...
while (mysqli_use_result($conn) && mysqli_next_result($conn));

echo 'done.';
$conn->close();
```

Comment: I can't find any info on the `mysqli_use_result` function on php.net.  What will the code `while (mysqli_use_result($conn) && mysqli_next_result($conn));` do?  I don't want to break anything :)

Comment: [mysqli_use_result](http://php.net/mysqli_use_result)

Comment: @user1477388 It just processes the results of the queries.

Comment: I ran the code but nothing happened.

Comment: @user1477388 Same error?

Comment: Yes, when I do `while (mysqli_use_result($conn) && mysqli_next_result($conn));var_dump($conn->error);` I get "MySQL server has gone away."

Answer (score 0):

Try ending your insert with a semi-colon ";" instead of the comma after your last tuple.

Comment: The code provided is just a sample.  The file is actually much larger.  It doesn't end with a comma; the SQL file was generated by phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Try mysqli_autocommit($conn, true); to force it to commit (I know it is supposed to be default). Also $conn->multi_query($sql) instead